# Perl YAML::Load fails to load YAML dumped by YAML::Dump

Tags: perl, yaml

I am facing this issue in [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/~tinita/YAML-1.18/lib/YAML.pod) when using through perl. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong.

I have a code snippet

```
use YAML;
...
my $ifdef_struct = YAML::Load(<<'DS_TEMPLATE');
---
'<define_name>': undef
DS_TEMPLATE
my @tmp;
push(@tmp, $ifdef_struct);
$ifdef_struct = \@tmp; 
print YAML::Dump($ifdef_struct);
```

This dumps out

```
    ---
    - '<define_name>': undef
```

Now when i change the code to have the same format as what is dumped by YAML::Dump

```
use YAML;
...
my $ifdef_struct = YAML::Load(<<'DS_TEMPLATE');
---
- '<define_name>': undef
DS_TEMPLATE
my @tmp;
push(@tmp, $ifdef_struct);
# $ifdef_struct = \@tmp;
print YAML::Dump($ifdef_struct);
```

it is not able to load it and gives me the error

```
Uncaught exception from user code:
    YAML Error: Couldn't parse single line value
       Code: YAML_PARSE_ERR_SINGLE_LINE
       Line: 2
       Document: 1
```

Any suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format `YAML` (the module) expects is:

```
---
-
    '<define_name>': undef
```

However,

```
---
- '<define_name>': undef
```

is valid YAML (the format).  If you read the documentation for `YAML`, you will find the following warning:

> If you want robust and fast YAML processing using the normal Dump/Load
>   API, please consider switching to YAML::XS. It is by far the best Perl
>   module for YAML at this time. It requires that you have a C compiler,
>   since it is written in C.

[`YAML::XS`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML-LibYAML/lib/YAML/XS.pod) has no problem with either version of the YAML:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use YAML::XS;
use Data::Dumper;
use warnings;

my $one_line = YAML::XS::Load(<<'EOS');
---
- '<define_name>': undef
EOS

my $multi_line = YAML::XS::Load(<<'EOS');
---
-
   '<define_name>': undef
EOS

print Dumper($one_line, $multi_line);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            '<define_name>' => 'undef'
          }
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          {
            '<define_name>' => 'undef'
          }
        ];
```